# How are Swift Package linked to an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have an Xcode project with an app Target and then some Swift Package dependencies.
I then add these dependencies in the *Frameworks*, *Libraries*, and *Embedded* content section of the general tab of the target configurations.

What binary format would these dependencies get to after the build, and if they would be linked to the main app statically or dynamically? And is there a way to control this process?

I didn't find clear documentation about it.

Answer (score 2):

Linking depends on how each library created by authors. In `Package.swift` you should check method [library(name:type:targets:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/product/library(name:type:targets:)) of specific SPM. If `type` parameter exist it will specify type of library and linkage type: `.static` or `.dynamic`, you can specify type when creating own SPM, link: [Product.Library.LibraryType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/product/library/librarytype). Otherwise and in most cases this parameter is avoided and Apple said:

> The optional type of the library that’s used to determine how to link
> to the library. Leave this parameter so Swift Package Manager can
> choose between static or dynamic linking (recommended). If you don’t
> support both linkage types, use Product.Library.LibraryType.static or
> Product.Library.LibraryType.dynamic for this parameter.
>
> A library’s product can be either statically or dynamically linked.
> It’s recommended that you don’t explicitly declare the type of
> library, so Swift Package Manager can choose between static or dynamic
> linking based on the preference of the package’s consumer. targets:
> The targets that are bundled into a library product.

Example:

```
let package = Package(name: "Alamofire",
                  platforms: [.macOS(.v10_12),
                              .iOS(.v10),
                              .tvOS(.v10),
                              .watchOS(.v3)],
                  products: [.library(name: "Alamofire",
                                      targets: ["Alamofire"])],
                  targets: ...
```

Static Type example:

```
let package = Package(
name: "IGListKit",
platforms: [ .iOS(.v9),
             .tvOS(.v9),
             .macOS(.v10_15),
],
products: [
    .library(name: "IGListDiffKit",
             type: .static ,
             targets: ["IGListDiffKit"]),
    .library(name: "IGListKit",
             type: .static,
             targets: ["IGListKit"])
],
targets: ...
```

Dynamic Type example:

```
var products: [Product] = [
.library(
    name: "SwiftGodot",
    type: .dynamic,
    targets: ["SwiftGodot"]),
.plugin(name: "CodeGeneratorPlugin", targets: ["CodeGeneratorPlugin"]),]
```

I found some resources in case leaving `LibraryType` as nil, Xcode defaults to building a static library when linking package into app:
[Swift Package Manager dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58090099/swift-package-manager-dynamic-library),
[WWDC NOTES: Creating Swift Packages](https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc19/410/).

I would recommend to rely on Apple documentation when type is avoided and left `nil`, otherwise specify exact `LibraryType` in case you need specific linkage type. Here are useful links to dig deeper: [SwiftPM and dynamic linking](https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftpm-and-dynamic-linking/53927), [PackageDescription](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/PackageDescription.md). The above mentioned is related to source-based package dependencies. If you need binary dependencies: [Identifying binary dependencies](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/identifying-binary-dependencies), [Distributing binary frameworks as Swift packages](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-binary-frameworks-as-swift-packages).
I hope this information will help you.